# How can I use cursor hover to change slides instead of clicking? I am trying to change slides when cursor is up on the slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanted to create a slideshow with some images inside a div. The slides will change continuously on hover over the slide. The will appear in a position at the top-left corner of the webpage. There are other divs and functionalities in the web page as well.

I used this section of code inside the div for slideshow. It works when I click on the dots. I used mostly inline styles. The rest classes are just for positioning and size of the div.

Here are the JavaScript css and html code respectably

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

css file

```
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

html file

```
<div role="list" class="banner__list w-dyn-items">
  <div style="background-image:url(/frontEnd/5a10aaa4d85f4b0001a5419a_2017-lamborghini-huracan-    spyder-orange-exterior-front-angle-royalty-exotic-cars.jpg)" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-   item mySlides">
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url(/frontEnd/5a10aaa4d85f4b0001a541d8_2015-bentley-continental-gtc-  red-car-hero-2-image-royalty-exotic-cars.jpg)" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url(/frontEnd/5abda7fc38a916291e1647d3_2018-jeep-wrangler-white-isolated-front-angle-royalty-exotic-cars.jpg)" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Currently slides changes when a dot is clicked. I want the slides to continuously go to the next slide as long as that hover is maintained. How can I do that?

Comment: elem..addEventListener("mouseover",...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: Use the onmouseover event to set a flag then set a timeout to cycle to the next slide if the flag in on. Use onmouseout to unset the flag. Have fun!

Comment: _" I want the slides to continuously go to the next slide as long as that **hover is maintained**."_ Sorry to sound dumb but you didn't tell where? (**hover is maintained**) whether only on dots or anywhere on the whole slide

Comment: on the slide @Viney

Answer (score 1):

Change `onclick` to `onmouseover` on the spans, like this:

```
<span class="dot" onmouseover="currentSlide(1)"></span>
<span class="dot" onmouseover="currentSlide(2)"></span>
<span class="dot" onmouseover="currentSlide(3)"></span>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for answer. Can I do it for the slide? I mean how can I do it when I put the cursor over the slide? TIA